# Can we get Google Status dashboard via API?

Tags: google-api, monitoring, google-apps

We are working on integrating Google Status dashboard into cachetHQ for our project, is there any way to get the status published in the link below via API?

https://www.google.com/appsstatus

Answer (score 0):

There is no api for app status but there is an RSS feed [RSS](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en)

You could use that.  its what i have done in the past